# Apache NiFi - The request contained an invalid host header

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm running an Apache NiFi instance using Docker at my workplace with a proxy in place. I pulled the official container down, spun up the container and set it to port over to 8081 instead of 8080 as the work proxy is set for 8080.

However when I try to access NiFi via the browser on my dev machine using `http://localhost:8081/nifi` I'm getting the following error appear

`System Error`

`The request contained an invalid host header [localhost:8081] in the request [/nifi]. Check for request manipulation or third-party intercept.`

I've found a couple of posts online mention the `nifi.properties` file, but I'm not very experienced with Docker outside of spinning up images.

If anyone can offer some guidance or a soltion that would be excellent. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the `nifi.properties` file directly, you can pass custom variables to the application during the Docker command using the `-e` flag. In your case, Docker is aware that port 8081 should map to 8080, but NiFi is not, and [detects a mismatch on the incoming request `host` header](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4824). To pass this through, try using a command like the following.

```
docker run --name nifi \
-p 8081:8081 \
-d \
-e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT='8081'
apache/nifi:latest
```

Comment: You sir, are a godsend! I'd somehow missed this very simple command from the Docker guide!

Comment: oh Andy you are like a god for us

Answer (score 2):

I was also struggling with the same issue. Below is my docker compose file

```
--- version: "3" services:   nifi:
    image: apache/nifi
    container_name: nifi
    volumes:
      - /home/user/nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/conf
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT:8443
      - NIFI_WBE_HTTP_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx
      - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx:8443
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME:admin
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD:ctsBtRBKHRAx69asEqUghvvgnaLjFEB
    restart: always
```

What helped was adding the below line

> ```
>   - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx:8443
> ```

I can access via my ip:8443 but the Username and Password are not working as of now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just specified the `nifi.web.http.host` property to the host IP and it works correctly.

File `nifi.properties`:

```
# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=192.168.0.69
nifi.web.http.port=8080
```

More info about that, I use the binary packages directly in my host. I think the hostname is not match the IP so nifi reported `System Error`.

For docker usage I'll find more later.

Answer (score -1):

I am using docker apache/nifi image which is having nifi_version : 1.14
After adding env variable **NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST** it worked without error

```
docker container  run --name nifi -p 8443:8443   -d -e NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=8443 -e NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST='192.168.100.100:8443'  apache/nifi:latest
```